# AIX and oracle: aioserver process won't die

Tags: aix, kill

When shutdown an oracle server I see this error message
at exit

```
umount /oracle/
umount: error unmounting /dev/oracle: Device busy
```

`lsof` and `fuser` report nothing
but

```
ps aux|grep oracle
```

report this

```
oracle    5964026  0,0  0,0  448  448      - A      apr 21  0:00 aioserver
oracle   10289224  0,0  0,0  448  448      - A    19:09:27  0:00 aioserver
oracle   11075692  0,0  0,0  448  448      - A    19:09:27  0:00 aioserver
oracle   11468902  0,0  0,0  448  448      - A    19:09:27  0:00 aioserver
oracle   13631648  0,0  0,0  448  448      - A    19:09:27  0:00 aioserver
oracle    3604680  0,0  0,0  448  448      - A    19:09:27  0:00 aioserver`
```

I try to kill with `kill -15` and also `kill -9` but they still alive

Using `pstree` I see this

```
 |--= 1966178 root aioPpool
 |--= 2228302 root aioLpool
 |--= 3604680 root aioserver
 |--= 5964026 root aioserver
 |--= 10289224 root aioserver
 |--= 11075692 root aioserver
 |--= 11468902 root aioserver
 \--= 13631648 root aioserver
```

Question is, how to kill those processes for umounting oracle?

If can help,here's the shutdown script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# description: Oracle auto start-stop script.
#
# Set ORACLE_HOME to be equivalent to the $ORACLE_HOME
# from which you wish to execute dbstart and dbshut;
#
# Set ORA_OWNER to the user id of the owner of the 
# Oracle database in ORACLE_HOME.

export ORA_OWNER=oracle
export ORACLE_BASE=/oracle/app
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=video
export ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER=$ORACLE_HOME
export TNS_ADMIN=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/freeware/sbin:/opt/freeware/bin:/opt/IBM/xlc/13.1.0/bin:/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/

if [ ! -f $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart ]
then
    echo "Oracle startup: cannot start"
    exit
fi

case "$1" in
    'start')
        # Start the Oracle databases:
        # The following command assumes that the oracle login 
        # will not prompt the user for any values
        # Remove "&" if you don't want startup as a background process.
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start" &
        su $ORA_OWNER -c $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart &
        ;;
    'stop')
        # Stop the Oracle databases:
        # The following command assumes that the oracle login 
        # will not prompt the user for any values
        su $ORA_OWNER -c $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        ;;
     'restart')
        stop
        start
        ;;
*)
echo "usage $0 start|stop|restart"
esac
```

Comment: Note: on AIX use `fuser -v /dev/mountdevice` instead of `fuser -vm /mount/point/`

Comment: fuser does not have a -v option on AIX, only -V which will not help: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/fuser.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aioserver is not keeping your filesystem busy, aioserver is an aix processes related to asynchroneous IO.

Probably there is another filesystem mounted over /oracle which is causing this problem:

```
mount | grep oracle
```

Also read [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b15658/appa_aix.htm#UNXAR330) to find out more regarding Oracle and the AIO usage.

Comment: The only fs mounted is oracle         ` /dev/oracle      /oracle          jfs2   Oct 19 20:41 rw,log=/dev/loglv00`

Comment: do you maybe have nmon running? or some other performance gathering tool running? where you maybe still cd'ed in /oracle, or somebody else on the system? did you try lsof and fuser -cux with /oracle or with /oracle/ (note the last /)

Comment: No nmon,lsof return nothing  fuser return some process,kill them and...nothing happen,still give me device busy

Comment: what processes did fuser give? did you check what it was? Are there any other users logged on to the system?

Comment: No user logging,fuser return some dead sqlplus process,i kill it no problem,but the partition still can't umounted

Comment: What fuser options did you use? Try fuser -cux